# Gatsby Cannot read property 'childImageSharp' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby, gatsby-image

I am building my first project with gatsby and can't find a solution to my problem with images.

My code is here [here](https://github.com/j3rrr/j3rrr.github.io)

When I try to run `gatsby build` I get this error:

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 10.907s

 ERROR #95313

Building static HTML failed for path "/posts/2"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  27 |                         return (
  28 |                             <div className={blogListStyles.cards}>
> 29 |                                 <Img sizes={node.frontmatter.screenshot.childImageSharp.sizes} />
     |                                                                         ^
  30 |                                 <Link to={`/blog/${node.fields.slug}`}>
  31 |                                 <div className={blogListStyles.title}>{node.frontmatter.title}</div>
  32 |                                 <div className={blogListStyles.subtitle} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: node.excerpt}}></div>


  WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'childImageSharp' of null

  - blog-list-template.js:29
    src/templates/blog-list-template.js:29:73

  - blog-list-template.js:25
    src/templates/blog-list-template.js:25:28
```

I found many solutions for this, but none of them worked for me, I even tried to setup a Linux Subsystem, cause I read that might fix issues, but it doesn't

I checked my .md files multiple times, but can't find any typo etc

When i run develop mode, /posts/2 will be a blank site

I would appreciate if anyone could have a look at my code, I am lost here :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post your graphql query, or tell me the path in the source code

Comment: of course i fixed it 10min after this post, but not in the 8h before.. there where indeed typos in my markdown files, and i also added a check to only add <Img> if the screenshot frontmatter is not null.. ty anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

added `{node.frontmatter.screenshot && <Img... />}` to my code, which did let me build it and then found out i did have typos in my markdown files, which i didnt see the 100 times i checked before -_-